# Image conversion from cartesian to polar and vice-versa in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, polar-coordinates

Let `I` be the original cartesian image, let `P` be the corresponding polar image created using `cv2.warpPolar()` and let `I'` be the cartesian image obtained after using `cv2.warpPolar(..., cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)` on `P`.
I understand that the process is lossy due to discretization, but quite a few features appear "pixellated" in `I'`.
Can this be prevented?
I'm using OpenCV in Python-3.

Comment: vary the parameters. what happens?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz What parameters? I tried using different interpolations while converting to polar but all of them gave similar results

Comment: parameters of the warpPolar function... you know, like `dsize`

Comment: Won't `dsize` always be `(maxRadius, 360)`?

Comment: no. you should try different values. in general it pays to have a sense of exploration.